# SQL Server time calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, sql-server-2012

I have the following table to capture timesheets of employees on the shop floor. The application is written in C# and SQL Server 2012.

Employees will enter in hours and minutes as a numeric field. When this is saves people can save 2 sets of 30 minutes making it 60 minutes and with a third entry on the same day it could be 75 minutes etc.

So my question is.

Is there a way that I could detect 75 minutes in the minutes field and increment the hour field by 1, leaving the remaining 15 in the minutes field.

Please see table in text format. I would be most grateful for any help

```
TSEID     EmpId     TimeTypeId     WeekNumber     WorksOrder     Process     Hours     Mins  
  39          1              1             21          X4769     Milling         6       75
```

Comment: There isn't a SQL Server 2012 R2. But anyway just store a single column of minutes and break back down to hours and minutes in the presentation layer. SQL server doesn't have a `timespan` datatype and `time` isn't suitable as it is not intended for this purpose and won't work for time amounts greater than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update TimeSheetTable
set Hours = Hours + Mins / 60, Mins = Mins % 60
where Mins >= 60
```